# Xcode Instruments Unknown Addresses

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-instruments

I'm using the Xcode Instruments tool to Time Profile my application. Unfortunately, no matter how much I interact with the application while recording, I don't see a comprehensive break down of function calls in the profile. Instead, I see these `<Unknown Address> [inlined]` messages.

Running on Simulated iPhone on Mac:
[image: Running on simulated iPhone on Mac]
Running on actual iPhone:
[image: Running on iPhone]

I verified that under the Xcode build options `DWARF with dSYM File` is selected for both `Debug` and `Release` and that the file exists. I'm using the IOS deployment target that matches the current version I have running on my iPhone and I have the latest (13.2.1) Xcode Command Line Tools selected.

I also took a look in Instruments > File > Symbols and noticed that there was a perms issue with what seems to be the CLT - not sure if this is at all related?

[image]

When I select the app name below `Unknown`, there isn't a dSYM path selected. However, every time I select it `/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-<sequence of characters>/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AppName.app.dSYM` I see a message "1 library will be symbolicated". However, this path doesn't seem to work because there is no behavior change in instruments AND it never sticks - it shows as empty if I open the window again.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!